# Returning odd or even number of characters from user input

Tags: python-3.x

Would someone please help me with the below code. If the user enters his name it should say the string has an even number of character or odd number of characters. Thank you

```
input_string = str(input("Please enter your name: "))

def evenodd(num):
    if(num % 2 == 0):
        print(num, "Is an even")
    else:
        print(num, "Is an odd")

evenodd(input_string)
```

Comment: In your function, replace num%2 with len(input_string) % 2. After that, call your function with evenodd(input_string)

Comment: you need to check the length of the string. use `num = len(input_string)` Then process `num`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num` is not defined. Assign it to the string argument's `len`:

```
input_string = str(input("Please enter your name: "))

def evenodd(s):
    num = len(s)  # <- here!
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return "even"
    else:
        return "odd"

print(evenodd(input_string))
```

I renamed the function argument to illustrate that it is completely independent from the `input_string` variable in the global scope.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the actual question is   using this function def evenodd(input_string):  I need to get these values                                                               
 1) -> that returns "even" if a string has an even number of characters                                                                                              
 2)-> that returns "odd" if a string has an odd number of characters.    just wondering is that a right code? TA

Comment: You mean, the function should return it, not print it?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
input_string = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
num = len(input_string)

def evenodd(input_string):
    if(num % 2 == 0):
        print(input_string, "Is an even")
    else:
        print(input_string, "Is an odd")

evenodd(num)
```

We used `len()` method to find the length of the string. Rest of the code was perfectly fine.

Comment: Just operating on global variables as you are, why keep `input_string` as a function parameter. In deed, why have a function at all?

Comment: @schwobaseggl The code in the question was MWE. It might be possible that its a small part of a big code where he had to use functions. Not sure but still agreeing with you :)